# Access point doesn't start with Raspberry Pi 3 built-in Wi-Fi

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, raspberry-pi3, access-point, hostapd

I have Raspberry Pi 3 and I use it as a Wi-Fi access point. I use Raspberry Pi 3 built-in Wi-Fi adapter for this.

Until today, the access point worked.

Today it stopped working. I think that Raspberry Pi crashed and I then turn the power off without shutting it down. Since then, it doesn't work.

If I run it as service, the status will show `running (exited)`.

When I run it with `sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`, I get the following errors and it doesn't work:

```
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=2 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x1018 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=1
nl80211: Create interface iftype 6 (MONITOR)
Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported)
nl80211: Driver does not support monitor interface type - try to run without it
nl80211: Enable Probe Request reporting nl_preq=0x1516038
nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_PROBE_REQ) nl_handle=0x1516038 match=
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=64): ret=-22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
nl80211: Failed to enable Probe Request frame reporting in AP mode
nl80211: QCA vendor test command returned -95 (Operation not supported)
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 3
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 3
phy: phy0
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Previous country code SI, new country code SI
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=SI (DFS-ETSI)
nl80211: 2402-2482 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5490-5710 @ 160 MHz 27 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 57000-66000 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=20 dBm
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 11  Frequency: 2462 MHz
DFS 0 channels required radar detection
nl80211: Set freq 2462 (ht_enabled=0, vht_enabled=0, bandwidth=20 MHz, cf1=2462 MHz, cf2=0 MHz)
  * freq=2462
  * vht_enabled=0
  * ht_enabled=0
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x1
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x1
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x1
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x1
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
hostapd_setup_bss(hapd=0x15159a0 (wlan0), first=1)
wlan0: Flushing old station entries
nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlan0 (all)
nl80211: Station flush failed: ret=-14 (Bad address)
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
wlan0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlan0 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> -110 (Connection timed out)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=1)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=2)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=3)
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr b8:27:eb:e7:72:18 and ssid "RaspberryCar"
Deriving WPA PSK based on passphrase
SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     52 61 73 70 62 65 72 72 79 43 61 72               RaspberryCar
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=16): [REMOVED]
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
GMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Get randomness: len=32 entropy=0
Key Counter - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: Delay group state machine start until Beacon frames have been configured
nl80211: Set beacon (beacon_set=0)
nl80211: Beacon head - hexdump(len=63): 80 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff b8 27 eb e7 72 18 b8 27 eb e7 72 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00 11 04 00 0c 52 61 73 70 62 65 72 72 79 43 61 72 01 08 82 84 8b 96 0c 12 18 24 03 01 0b
nl80211: Beacon tail - hexdump(len=37): 2a 01 04 32 04 30 48 60 6c 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 02 00 00 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: ifindex=3
nl80211: beacon_int=100
nl80211: dtim_period=2
nl80211: ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     52 61 73 70 62 65 72 72 79 43 61 72               RaspberryCar
  * beacon_int=100
nl80211: hidden SSID not in use
nl80211: privacy=1
nl80211: auth_algs=0x1
nl80211: wpa_version=0x2
nl80211: key_mgmt_suites=0x2
nl80211: pairwise_ciphers=0x18
nl80211: group_cipher=0x10
nl80211: beacon_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: proberesp_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: assocresp_ies - hexdump(len=6): 7f 04 00 00 00 02
nl80211: Beacon set failed: -110 (Connection timed out)
Failed to set beacon parameters
wlan0: Flushing old station entries
nl80211: flush -> DEL_STATION wlan0 (all)
nl80211: Station flush failed: ret=-14 (Bad address)
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
wlan0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlan0 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> -110 (Connection timed out)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=0)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=1)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=2)
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=3 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
nl80211: set_key failed; err=-22 Invalid argument)
Failed to clear default encryption keys (ifname=wlan0 keyidx=3)
hostapd_free_hapd_data(wlan0)
Interface initialization failed
wlan0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED
wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x1514cd8)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x1514cd8)
wlan0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan0
wlan0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: sta_remove -> DEL_STATION wlan0 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff --> -110 (Connection timed out)
wlan0: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x15159a0 (wlan0))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=0xd8b84 drv_priv=0x1516328 -> hapd_deinit
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=3)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
hostapd_interface_free(0x1514cd8)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x15159a0
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x1514cd8)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x1514cd8)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x1514cd8
```

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wireless-mode Master ### <--- It is same without this line
```

This is my `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211

ssid=RaspberryCar

hw_mode=g
channel=11
country_code=SI

wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0

auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

And output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.64.127  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.64.255
        inet6 fe80::cc5e:510f:4686:fcb3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:b2:27:4d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10883  bytes 709212 (692.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2471  bytes 500246 (488.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 800  bytes 55840 (54.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 800  bytes 55840 (54.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:e7:72:18  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access point started working now, but I didn't change anything. Maybe there were some corrupted files, but the system repaired them after a few reboots.

I also got answers on [Raspberry Pi Forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=234202) by [epoch1970](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=189739). I don't know if they would fix the problem, but they are mostly about corrupted files, so they probably fix the problems.